# Ionic - Modal Select Option for filter content with ng-repeat and http-get

Tags: angularjs, http, ionic-framework, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on my first IONIC-App with AngularJS and I am lead into a dead end.

What I trying to do? There is a overview page with list-elements from a database. The elements comes with ng-repeat, and the $scope-array get filled by an Get-Request via an factory and an OverviewCtrl.

Now the user should have the option to filter stuff. Therefore I like to bring up a modal-windows where the user can select from a selection list. When he select an option the modal should close and the overview-page where he comes from should update.

I try to describe the problem clear as possible:

HTML:
There is this filter.html page (for test reasons, I called it in that way). It gets the "OverviewCtrl" via the app.js. On the page is something like this, to render the overview-elements:

```
            <a class="item item-thumbnail-left"  ng-repeat="x in overviews" >
            <img src="{{x.pic}}">
            <p>{{x.text}}</p>
        </a>
```

So far so good. Also on this filter.html we have this code here, to open the modal:

> ```
>         <div class="buttons">
>             <button class="button icon-right ion-ios7-arrow-down button-clear button-dark" ng-click="openModal()">
>                 {{modalData.msg}}
>             </button>
>         </div>
> ```
>
> works fine too.

**Factory**

I got a factory where all the different HTTP-Get-Requests are realised. So there is also one for the filter. This works all fine, I can see it on the console.

I am returning the callback and in the controller I save it to the $scope.Overview.

Looks like this:

```
        return {listFilter:function(callback){
        $http.get("url...").success(callback).error(callback);
    }};
```

Controllers:

**AppCtrl:**

In the AppCtrl controller are the information for the modal-window like in this example:
[Example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/qGLBh)

So the Modal-Window gets its template also in this controller which looks like this:

```
<div class="modal" ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Choose wisely</h1>
    <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="hideModal()">Cancel</button>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <div class="list">
        <ion-radio ng-model="modalData.msg" ng-repeat="x in filter" ng-click="setFilter(x)">
            {{x}}
        </ion-radio>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**OverviewCtrl**

Here happens most of the magic. The OverviewCtrl calls by starting the app the factory getData and fills the overviews scope with data. The factory is described later in this post.

**ModalCtrl**

One fact is, that I first try to use all in one controller which means I had just the OverviewCtrl. But then ng-repeat won't update because there were two kinds of the $scope.overview. One for the ModalCtrl and one for the OverviewCtrl because there where both in the filter.html.

So I try to fix that problem and now I am at the dead end. When I try to call the factory for the Get-Request in the ModalCtrl and write the returned data in the Overview-Scope, the view won't update with ng-repeat.  And I am quite sure, that is because I need to call the factory via the OverviewCtrl, right? But thats not possible, because the event comes over the ModalCtrl. Or am I having a big mistake here?

Hope I did not forget something, sorry I am really new to AngularJS and maybe I am not so good in a Description for my problem. Also I am not sure that I finally found the problem, it is just a presumption. Does anyone had another idea? I spend hours for a solution and I am not sure there is one out there. I think it is very complicate with this modal-select, maybe I should try a normal select.

Comment: So meanwhile I solved this problem with just using the ion-select directive. With this modal-thing it was too complicated.

Comment: hi, if still interested in this kind of interaction, just check out my ionic-modal-select directive https://github.com/inmagik/ionic-modal-select